# How to Input QR Code Data in to Sqlite Table?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Hi i'm trying to put QR Data to my database table. But when I scan this error appears:

> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting near "10": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO BSIT103_BSIT3(10/24,STUDENT_NO,NAME) VALUES (?,?,?), (OS error - 11:Try again)

ClassDB:

```
public boolean insertStudent(String type, String data, String data1){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String student[] = type.split(":");
    contentValues.put(COL_6, student[0]);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, student[1]);
    contentValues.put(data, student[2]);
    long result = db.insert(data1,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    Intent sIntent = getIntent();
    ExampleClassInfo sClass = sIntent.getParcelableExtra("selected");
    String selCode = sClass.getiCode();
    String selDate = sClass.getiDate();

    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (result != null)
    {
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            boolean isInserted = classDB.insertStudent(result.getContents(),selDate,selCode);
            if(isInserted){
                exampleClassArrayList.clear();
                createClassList();
                exampleClassArrayList = classDB.getAllInfromation2(selCode,selDate);
                buildRecycleView();
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

Custom QR Code data:

> example : example : example

Comment: `contentValues.put(data, student[2]);` – Why are you using `data` for the key, there? Don't you want to use some `COL_*` for that?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
db.insert(data1,null,contentValues);
```

inserts into the table with name the value of the variable `data1` a row with the values you have assigned to `contentValues`.
Is your table's name the value of the variable `data1`?
Also this line:

```
contentValues.put(data, student[2]);
```

assigns `student[2]` to the column with name the value of the variable `data`.
Is this the correct name of the column?
I don't think so, it should have a name like `COL_4` or similar like the other columns of the table. 
The error you get points that you use as table name: `BSIT103_BSIT3` and as column name: `10/24` which of course is not allowed (if it is a column's name) and it should be enclosed in square brackets or backticks since it starts with a number and contains illegal character `/`.